# Prolog replace all occurrences of an element by another element in a Tree

Tags: prolog

A binary tree is defined as follows:

```
tree(-). % empty tree.
tree(n(X,L,R)) :- tree(L), tree(R).
```

I have to write a predicate `replace(X,Y,OldTree,NewTree)` that replaces all occurrences of `X` by `Y`. I have managed to write this so far but I think it's wrong :

```
replace(_,_,n,n).
replace(Old,New,n(X,L,R),n(X,L1,R1)) :-
    replace(Old,New,L,L1),
    replace(Old,New,R,R1).
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Do you have some examples why you think it's wrong?

Answer (score 1):

```
replacement(X, Y, TX, TY) :-
   if_(X = TX, Y = TY, TX = TY).
```

This replaces one element using `library(reif)` for [SICStus](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/Prolog-inedit/sicstus/reif.pl) or [SWI](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/Prolog-inedit/swi/reif.pl).

Now we need to replace all elements, so we will apply `replacement/4` a couple of times. Some part will remain the same, and some of it will change.  In fact, the first two arguments will always be the same, only the last two change.  So we could write `call(replacement(X,Y), TX, TY)`.  In fact, we could now define that relation over the trees independently of our concrete replacement-relation:

```
maptree(_R_2, n, n).
maptree(R_2, n(TX, L0, R0), n(TY, L, R)) :-
   call(R_2, TX, TY),
   maptree(R_2, L0, L),
   maptree(R_2, R0, R).

replace(X, Y, TX, TY) :-
   maptree(replacement(X,Y), TX, TY).
```